# why does npm install a version of angular cli that it cannot use?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I've used nvm to install the following version of node, which comes with its own version of npm.

```
(base) PS C:\src\Demo\FrontEnd> node --version
v16.13.2
```

```
(base) PS C:\src\Demo\FrontEnd> npm --version
8.1.2
```

By default, there is no angular cli installation that comes with this version. So I install it using `npm install -g @angular/cli`, then check the version, only for it to complain that
`The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.13.` Why does npm do this? What is the correct version to install here?

```
(base) PS C:\src\Demo\FrontEnd> ng version
ng : The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ng version
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ng:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

(base) PS C:\src\Demo\FrontEnd> npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
...
}

added 228 packages, and audited 230 packages in 7s

found 0 vulnerabilities
(base) PS C:\src\Demo\FrontEnd> ng version
Node.js version v16.13.2 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.13.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.
```

Comment: It is not NPM's job to check that. You asked NPM to install the latest version of the Angular CLI which it did and seems to be incompatible with your current NodeJS version.

Comment: Just a sidenote, try to avoind using `powershell` when using node related stuff since it will - most likely - results in some kind of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Angular CLI does come with some internal prerequisites, that do require a higher node version to perform complex file operations (generators, installation, deployment, library generation, etc.). Those complex functions are simply not included in earlier node.js versions. So Angular is telling you to basically update your node.js.

With nvm, as you know, this is super easy to achieve.

```
nvm install 18
nvm use 18
```

You can now re-run your global installation of @angular/cli and everything should be running like charm.

Have a great day.